# Как получить GDB для Windows?

Tags: windows, gdb

На [сайте](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) проекта GNU по отладчику GDB ссылка на страницу загрузки ведет на [зеркало](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/), где выложены архивы с исходниками.

Если где-нибудь страница с готовыми сборками под разные операционные системы, в частности, под Windows. Или надо самому собирать из исходников? Если да, то с помощью каких средств это делать на Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите проект [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW) (если нужны native windows). Если native не обязательно, то можно cygwin.

Answer (score 5):

После установки mingw, установите из списка gcc. Если заново открыть mingw вы увидите еще больше доступных файлов(packages) для установки. В списке , найдите mingw32-gdb , и рассавьте галочки (около 5 , для man , info и прочих дополнений к gdb)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]